# Tab through headings without cycling through showall in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

In org mode in Doom Emacs, i am used, that i am just cycling through the next heading and close it right after that.

But in vanilla Emacs, I am cycling through three stages (for whatever reason). How can i avoid this in vanilla Emacs?

Or is there a "close only the heading of this subtree" function?

For example, let the file be:

```
* test1
** test2
   hello
```

In Doom Emacs, it shows

```
* test1 ...
```

pressing tab shows

```
* test1
**test2...
```

pressing tab should now close it again:

```
* test1...
```

instead in vanilla Emacs it shows

```
* test1
** test2
   hello
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. In particular, Org mode *IS* in vanilla emacs, so I don't understand the difference between your first and second paragraph. Is the buffer in the second case not an Org mode buffer? Maybe you can provide a more detailed example and say exactly what the buffer contains and what you are doing in each case.

Comment: @NickD I provided an example, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: But you are still contrasting "Org mode" vs "vanilla Emacs" which does not make sense. Are you talking about "Doom Emacs" vs "vanilla Emacs" as the answer below surmises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a solution to your problem but rather a referral to one, which I suspect would do what you want. If the non-vanilla version of Emacs you used to use before was Doom Emacs, then, in Doom Emacs, the behaviour of the `org-cycle` bound to `TAB` has been changed by adding a hook called `+org-cycle-only-current-subtree-h` to `org-tab-first-hook`. This function is located in https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs/blob/master/modules/lang/org/autoload/org.el You can just copy paste it from there.

The hook is applied as in the following code snippet from Doom Emacs, I have removed a few irrelevant things from it:

```
 (add-hook 'org-tab-first-hook
           ;; Only fold the current tree, rather than recursively
            #'+org-cycle-only-current-subtree-h)
```

Please NOTE, I haven't tested this in any way!

Comment: Works perfectly.